# backbone model.destroy doesn't remove the model nor from collection

Tags: backbone.js

triggering the `model.destroy()` triggers a **delete** request to the server and server sents back `success:true`, I have an event listener on the `view.model` listening on `destroy`. after all this I can still see the model still exist on the view. and the collection also doesn't remove the model..

Updated ...

this happens only after updating the model and calling on delete on it again. if the model was there during loading it would be delete but the view still hold a link to the model. so the model is really not made null/destroyed

Comment: After succesfully deleting model, [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-remove) the model from collection and DOM ( you can use [Ravi's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19971191/1746258)  ). Than render your view

Answer (score 1):

I think view will not get removed from DOM, when you remove the model that used to render the view. You have to add some listener to remove view when model is removed.

```
view.listenToOnce(view.model, 'destroy', function(){
    view.remove();
})
```